# Sum a subset of a second df

Tags: r

I have this two tables and need to calculate totalMilk as the sum of prod in df2 between df1$date1 and df1$date2 where eartag = eartag. Would anyone please give me a hint? thanks heaps in advance. Jose

```
library(lubridate)

df1 <- data.frame(eartag = 1:10,
                  date1 = dmy("10/10/16"),
                  date2 = dmy("10/03/17"),
                  totalMilk=NA)

df2 <- data.frame(eartag = rep(1:10,each = 10),
                  edate = rep(dmy("10/10/16") + days(1:10), times = 10),
                  prod = round(runif(100,0.5,3),1))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are multiple paths to follow, such as base R, `dplyr`, and `data.table`, each with their pros/cons. Consider the simple problem first: how would you determine which of `df2$edate` is between one date and another date. From there it's just a matter of iterating over `df1`, row-by-row.

Comment: Done, thanks a lot.